# BS3 carousel + animate.min.css not working perfectly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animate.css

I am using firefox 33.0 in Ubuntu 14.04. I have a website(localhost) with bootstrap 3 carousel. I have applied "animated pulse" (animate.min.css) class to my "img" in the "class=item" div and "animated fadeinleft" to my carousel-caption.

```
<div class="item">
   <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive animated pulse">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
               <h1 class="animated fadeinleft">Another example headline.</h1>
               <p class="animated fadeinright">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

There are 3 slides in total. For the first appearance of each slide, the image and carousel caption  comes with the effect (animate.min.css). But after that the slides just comes and goes without any effect. This happens only in firefox. In Chrome 38.0.2125.104 it works as expected. Somebody please suggest a way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the example on their [site](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) the classes are applied and if you want to trigger again you need to remove and add classes again. That is how CSS3 animation is restarted or triggered again by removing and adding classes again. You can read more about this [here](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/). In your case the classes are not removed and added again.

For Bootstrap you can use the `slide.bs.carousel` where you can add the classes again. I have added a data attribute [data-animation] to the elements for the respective animation.

```
<div class="active item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/750" alt="Slide1" class="img-responsive animated pulse" data-animation="pulse" />
    <div class="container">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
           <h1 class="animated fadeInLeft" data-animation="fadeInLeft">Another example headline.</h1>

           <p class="animated fadeInRight" data-animation="fadeInRight">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
function animateElement(obj, anim_) {
    obj.addClass(anim_ + ' animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

    var current = $('.item').eq(parseInt($(e.relatedTarget).index()));
    $('[data-animation]').removeClass();
    $('[data-animation]', current).each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var anim_ = $this.data('animation');
        animateElement($this, anim_);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7TdVu/359/)

Comment: Why does it work in Chrome but not in FF without your suggested modification?

Comment: @arshad Animation has issues in Firefox and  IE if the element is hidden so the animation should be done after the element is shown. [Chrome waits for the element to be shown before animation starts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24589834/473016). Hence the only way is to trigger the animation is to add the class after the element is shown/slid.

Comment: Is this the easiest way?

Comment: @arshad This seems to be a browser bug and there have been many issues reported too. [1](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/172), [2](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/269). Even [here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/#animations) its said that `Setting the display property to none will terminate any running animation applied to the element and its descendants` so I feel the only way to restart the animations is by adding class again.

Comment: Thats what I asked.. Is this the only way to add and remove classes? Is there something like "`if (inviewport){addclass} else{removeclass}`"?

Comment: @arshad No.You will have to know which div is active so you can't avoid the calculation with `$(e.relatedTarget).index()` and data attribute is because you have elements with different animation. And the event in function `animateElement` is done as I saw `animate.css` removing class on animation end.