# Firefox CSS doesn't animate but Chrome does

Tags: css, firefox, animation

I have a relatively simple Fiddle, that I've mucked up with additional @-webkit- and @-moz- duplicates, but it still fails on Firefox.

```
div.overlay-dialogue {  
    ...
    animation: ANIM_NAME 0.5s ease-in-out; 
} 

@keyframes ANIM_NAME {  
    0% { transform: rotateY(55deg); opacity: 0; }  
    100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); opacity: 1; }  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxpuL6ea/4/

Can anyone see why??

Comment: And here is the simpler first version that still works in Chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/vc8u4yvx/

Comment: You can look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589537/firefox-animation-not-starting-on-toggle-display-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from another question: [Firefox animation not starting on toggle display style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589537/firefox-animation-not-starting-on-toggle-display-style)

> Firefox and Internet Explorer are rightfully running the animation
>   regardless of the display state

So to work this around, you can set `animation` to `checked` state, like this:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div.overlay-dialogue {  
    display: block;
    animation: ANIM_NAME 0.5s ease-in-out; 
    ...
}
```