# FIrefox animate.css animations not consistent

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, animate.css

[Rock, Paper, Scissors!](http://teias.eu/en/demo/rps.html)
 Hi there,

I've been trying my skills at coding an html game using [these](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) amazing CSS3 animations with jQuery and Firefox is letting me down. For some reason the browser only plays the first time around, leaving all subsequent plays without animation. Any help with debugging would be much appreciated. So far setting the width of the elements over doesn't seem to work. Maybe on a better day.

Comment: Stab in the dark: Maybe this is your problem, [Firefox animation not starting on toggle display style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589537/firefox-animation-not-starting-on-toggle-display-style/24589834) ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Code has grown a bit maybe I'll follow your advice and post a proper example. Whichever case it seems rudimentary tactics get Firefox to keep alive. It still doesn't do all the animations I would expect it to.

Comment: Alexander thanks for you reply. I'm not sure I'm ready to expose all the subterfuges I went through to get an idea like this to work. Maybe it's not an ideal model to begin with an it's a wonder it works at all in the end. Maybe embarrassing. Whichever case it's only Mozilla that's playing difficult. A bit disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

Current Firefox implementations fail unless time values of 0 have units. Use 0s or 0ms. then it will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Firefox is not an easy browser to work with. It seems changing the content of a div on the fly causes the animation attached to it not to play when the page loads. A little disappointing all other browsers are playing nice.